# Consuming JSON post Jersey

Tags: json, rest, post, gwt, jersey

My application has two modules - frontend and backend.
In order to make frontend I use GWT framework.
On the backend I've used Jersey.
These two modules should communicate in SOA trough REST,
data exchange format - JSON.
My question is how can I receive JSON from GWT.
My code looks like below but it is not working and I have no idea why.
So I stuck. I'm sending JSON in GWT by RequestBuilder:

```html
private void sendServerProperties() {
    String path = FrontendModuleConfiguration.runningBackendServerAddress;
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, path);
    try {
        builder.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String v1 = POP3ServerAdressField.getText();
        String v2 = addressField.getText();
        String v3 = passwordField.getText();

        final JSONObject serverPropertiesJSON = new JSONObject();
        serverPropertiesJSON.put("host", new JSONString(v1));
        serverPropertiesJSON.put("user", new JSONString(v2));
        serverPropertiesJSON.put("password", new JSONString(v3));

        // try {
        Request response = builder.sendRequest(serverPropertiesJSON.toString(), new RequestCallback() {

                    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                        Window.alert("There was an error!" + exception.getMessage());
                    }

                    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                        System.out.println("------ LOG ------");
                        System.out.println("Below JSON has been sent:");
                        System.out.println(serverPropertiesJSON.toString());
                    }});
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        Window.alert("Unable to build the request.");
    }
}
```

I try to retrieve this JSON by Jersey:

```html
@Path("/emails")
public class EmailHandler {
 
 private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

    @POST
    @Path("/getemails")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response checkEmails(ServerProperties serverProperties){
     String output = serverProperties.toString();
     return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }}
```

My POJO looks like this:

```html
public class ServerProperties {

 private String host;
 private String user;
 private String password;
 
 private String getHost() {
  return this.host;
 }
 public void setHost(String host) {
  this.host = host;
 }
 public String getUser() {
  return this.user;
 }
 public void setUser(String user) {
  this.user = user;
 }
 public String getPassword() {
  return this.password;
 }
 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }
 
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return new StringBuffer(" Host : ").append(this.host)
                  .append(" User : ").append(this.user)
                  .append(" Password : ").append(this.password).toString();
 }
 
 public ServerProperties(){
  
 }
 
 public ServerProperties(String host, String user, String password){
  this.password=password;
  this.host=host;
  this.user=user;
 }

}
```

My web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.wp.projekt.tomasz.murglin.backend</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>readme.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.wp.projekt.tomasz.murglin.backend</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite obviously JSON is not form-urlencoded:

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, path);
try {
    builder.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

…

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Comment: Ok. Then what type isnstead of "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ?

Comment: Ok, I've changed "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to "multipart/form-data" but I still dont see any console output in the function which should consume JSON, so there is still a problem...

Comment: Your server side code is expecting `application/json`, and you're sending JSON, so just tell the server what you're actually sending (which happens to be what it expects)